# Outputting the value of dynamically created AMPScript variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, dynamic

In an email, I am using SSJS (I know, frowned upon) to parse out a JSON string.

```
%%[ var @resourceCount ]%% 
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var json = '[ { "Resource":"http://www.yahoo.com" }, { "Resource":"http://www.google.com" } ]'

// Parse JSON
var jsonObject = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(json);
var list = jsonObject;

// Loop through all items in the list (JSON)
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    var listItem = list[i];

    // Set List item info
    var resource = listItem['Resource'];

    // Set variabele name
    var loopNr = (i+1); // Add 1 because loop starts at 0
    var variableName = ("@resource"+loopNr); // Combine word title with number of loop

    // Write variabele to AMPscript for further processing
    Platform.Variable.SetValue(variableName, resource);
    Platform.Variable.SetValue("@resourceCount", loopNr)
}
</script>
```

As you can see towards the bottom of the script, I have:

```
var variableName = ("@resource"+loopNr); // Combine word title with number of loop
Platform.Variable.SetValue(variableName, resource);
```

So what we end up having is a number of AMPScript variables such as `@resource1`, `@resource2`, and so on.  The unknown here is how many of these variables I will end up having.  Could be 1, could be 10.

Once I have these variables created and set with data, I then try to output them into the email. That's where I'm having issues.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    %%[ for @counter = 1 to @resourceCount do  
       SET @tempValue = Concat('@resource', @counter)
     ]%%
      <tr>
       <td>
         %%=RedirectTo(@tempValue)=%%
       </td>
      </tr>
     %%[ next @counter ]%%
</table>
```

As one would probably expect, what's being output is the literal AMPScript variable - example: `@resource1`, `@resource2`, and so on.  I need to be able to output the contents OF these variables.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Just as a note I highly recommend SSJS in email to parse JSON

Comment: Also likely putting a treatascontent around it should work to treat the concatted string as an ampscript var. Here is an article I wrote that should be able to provide more info on outputting it: https://gortonington.com/dynamically-creating-variables-in-ampscript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `@tempValue` dynamically in this case and then correctly interpret the content of it by the [TreatAsContent](https://ampscript.guide/treatascontentarea/) function. In the end, you would have something like this for immediate [redirect](https://ampscript.guide/redirect/) -

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    %%[ for @counter = 1 to @resourceCount do  
      @new_variable = TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%', '%[SET @tempValue = @resource', @counter, ']%', '%'))
     ]%%
      <tr>
       <td>
         %%=Redirect(@tempValue)=%%
       </td>
      </tr>
     %%[ next @counter ]%%
</table>
```

If you would want to set links on the page dynamically and then let users get redirected by clicking on them, then you need to use [RedirectTo](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) within the `<a>` HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<script runat="server">
//your previous logical code here
// Loop through all items in the list (JSON)
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    var listItem = list[i];

    // Set List item info
    var resource = listItem['Resource'];

    // Set variabele name
    var loopNr = (i+1); // Add 1 because loop starts at 0
    var variableName = ("@resource"); 

    // Write variable to AMPscript for further processing
    Platform.Variable.SetValue(variableName, resource);
</script>

<tr>
   <td>
      %%=RedirectTo(@resource)=%%
   </td>
</tr>

<script runat="server">
}
</script>

</table>
```